# Opencv Gem bundle install error in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, opencv, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have cloned the opencv from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4.0

and then i installed in my ubuntu 12.04 using

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#building-opencv-from-source-using-cmake-using-the-command-line.

After installing using the above document,

I added 'gem 'ruby-opencv' ,'0.0.8'' in Gemfile of my application.

bundle install throws the below error,

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/vijaya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
>> Check the required libraries...
checking for main() in -lopencv_calib3d... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_contrib... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_core... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_features2d... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_flann... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_gpu... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_highgui... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_imgproc... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_legacy... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_ml... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_objdetect... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_video... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_photo... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_nonfree... yes
checking for main() in -lstdc++... yes
>> Check the required headers...
checking for opencv2/core/core_c.h... yes
checking for opencv2/core/core.hpp... yes
checking for opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h... yes
checking for opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp... yes
checking for opencv2/video/tracking.hpp... yes
checking for opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp... yes
checking for opencv2/flann/flann.hpp... yes
checking for opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp... yes
checking for opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp... yes
checking for opencv2/legacy/compat.hpp... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/vijaya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
    --with-opencv-dir
    --without-opencv-dir
    --with-opencv-include
    --without-opencv-include=${opencv-dir}/include
    --with-opencv-lib
    --without-opencv-lib=${opencv-dir}/lib
    --with-libxml2-dir
    --without-libxml2-dir
    --with-libxml2-include
    --without-libxml2-include=${libxml2-dir}/include
    --with-libxml2-lib
    --without-libxml2-lib=${libxml2-dir}/lib
    --with-opencv_calib3dlib
    --without-opencv_calib3dlib
    --with-opencv_contriblib
    --without-opencv_contriblib
    --with-opencv_corelib
    --without-opencv_corelib
    --with-opencv_features2dlib
    --without-opencv_features2dlib
    --with-opencv_flannlib
    --without-opencv_flannlib
    --with-opencv_gpulib
    --without-opencv_gpulib
    --with-opencv_highguilib
    --without-opencv_highguilib
    --with-opencv_imgproclib
    --without-opencv_imgproclib
    --with-opencv_legacylib
    --without-opencv_legacylib
    --with-opencv_mllib
    --without-opencv_mllib
    --with-opencv_objdetectlib
    --without-opencv_objdetectlib
    --with-opencv_videolib
    --without-opencv_videolib
    --with-opencv_photolib
    --without-opencv_photolib
    --with-opencv_nonfreelib
    --without-opencv_nonfreelib
    --with-stdc++lib
    --without-stdc++lib
extconf.rb:64:in `block in <main>': opencv2/legacy/compat.hpp not found. (RuntimeError)
    from extconf.rb:57:in `each'
    from extconf.rb:57:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vijaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@vijay/gems/ruby-opencv-0.0.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vijaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@vijay/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/ruby-opencv-0.0.8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing ruby-opencv (0.0.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ruby-opencv -v '0.0.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am Using Ruby Verison - 2.1.1

Rails Verison - 4.1.1

Can any one help me in fixing this issue?

Comment: Try to manually copy [this](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/legacy/include/opencv2/legacy/compat.hpp) to `/usr/include/opencv2/legacy/`?

Comment: don't invest too much time on this, it's horribly outdated.